# Why do my bitmap have strange pixel errors when displayed on top of another bitmap on canvas

Tags: android

I am drawing a bitmap (ball) onto a SurfaceView canvas and then right after I am drawing a new bitmap (shine) to make it appear on top of the ball bitmap, and I am adjusting the shine bitmap alpha up and down to animate it as a shine/glow. But the shine bitmap seems to have some strange pixel errors when it is drawn and the more alpha I give it the worse it is.

Look at the result here: [image], those blue/red pixels are not present on the png i use.

Here is my init on the ball object:

```
sparklePaint = new Paint();
sparklePaint.setAlpha(0);
```

and then my anmation method on the ball object:

```
public void doAnimate() {
    if (sparkleAnimating) {
        if (sparklePaint.getAlpha() == 255) {
            sparkleOpcatyUp = false;
        }
        if (sparkleOpcatyUp) {
            int opacity = sparklePaint.getAlpha() + sparkleOpacityStep;
            if (opacity > 255) {
                opacity = 255;
            }
            sparklePaint.setAlpha(opacity);
        } else {
            int opacity = sparklePaint.getAlpha() - sparkleOpacityStep;
            if (opacity < 0) {
                opacity = 0;
            }
            sparklePaint.setAlpha(opacity);
            if (opacity == 0) {
                sparkleOpcatyUp = true;
                sparkleAnimating = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        sparkleAnimTick++;
        if (sparkleAnimTick == sparkleAnimDelay) {
            sparkleAnimTick = 0;
            sparkleAnimating = true;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my draw loop:

```
for (Ball ball : balls) {
    if (ball != null && ball.getBitmap() != null) {
        int[] pos = ball.getPos();
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), pos[0], pos[1], null);

        pos = ball.getSparklePos();
        canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getSparkle(), pos[0], pos[1], ball.getSparklePaint());
        ball.doAnimate();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on what goes wrong here? Is that not the way to draw bitmap on top of another bitmap? Is it some blending mode I need to set?

The problem is present both on emulator and device.

Thank you

Søren

Comment: Are you using a Paint to draw the ball and shine (and the first Xmas app on SO :))

Comment: Yes I create a Paint for each shine object and reuse that paint for every drawBitmap call (the ball has no paint object) and set the alpha on the shine paint object as needed.

Comment: Did you try Paint.setDither() and/or Paint.setAntiAlias()?

Comment: setDither(true) works quite well, now there are only very little pixel errors left, thank you. So I can not get it to be perfect?

Comment: Try a Paint for the ball as well, if only to set the dithering.

Comment: Not it gives the same result. But it is good enough for my use, so you can make it a answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Paint.setDither() and Paint.setAntiAlias() on the paints for drawing the ball and shine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have found some odd pixel errors with canvas.
For example if you draw a line, then draw over it in a different color, then some of the pixels aren't what they should be.

for example, this code draws a rectangle, then draws over it in white which should erase it, but it does not fully!

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 ctx.lineWidth=1;     
 ctx.strokeStyle="black"; 
 ctx.beginPath();   
 ctx.strokeRect( 100, 50, 400, 300 );
 ctx.stroke();

 alert("Redraw in white");

 ctx.strokeStyle="white"; // clear previous line   
 ctx.beginPath();   
 ctx.strokeRect( 100, 50, 400, 300 );
 ctx.stroke();

</script>
```